# Can you publish asp.net webforms project keeping it online?

Tags: asp.net, iis

We've quite a big project at work which sometimes needs  to be published during the day. However, the application will (of course) crash during publish and show errors. (because the /bin is being overwritten)

Is there a way to avoid this? Sometimes a publish takes up to  3-4 minutes.

I know I can use the app_offline.htm file to display a  message instead of them seeing the actual errors.

Comment: Yes, I sometimes have to do this. I publish my sites with 'use fixed naming and single page assemblies' ticked. If I have an emergency fix that has to go live - I publish the site to a temporary folder, copy the whole live site, and then drop the modified .aspx file and its associated dll into the appropriate folders and the change is instant. Never had anyone notice yet.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way to have 0 downtime on a deployment. But you have some options

### Deploy a pre-compiled site

To speed up the time taken for a site to be active after deployment, you can use [ASP.NET Web Site Pre-compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228015(v=vs.85).aspx). This process will package the site so that it will not need to be compiled on-the-fly after deployment.

#### Benefits

- Faster site startup
- Less assets to deploy
- Can be packaged via the Web Deployment Tool

#### Drawbacks

- Debugging can be harder as the names are scrambled; Debug mode can be turned on for it though
- You cannot edit a pre-compiled site; you must do a full re-deployment
- You should still use the app_offline.htm so avoid yellow-screen-of-death errors

### Add another web server

The best option for these scenarios is to have 2 servers with a load balancer in front of them. Then this way you use the load balancer to redirect active traffic to one node while the new application is being deployed.

#### Benefits

- Parallel deployments do not affect the existing site
- Have double the capacity for future expansion
- Load balancing allows the load to be spread evenly across servers.

#### Drawbacks

- Session now needs to be stored out-of-process. Therefore, you must check you can switch to an [out-of-process session storage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754032(v=ws.10).aspx) to confirm you do not have any serialization problems. `StateServer` is a quick one to get started with locally.
- More maintenance overhead for a deployment, as you need to include load balancing configuration as part of your deployment processes. Network Admins are normally familiar with this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, at least I have some options visible now.

Comment: @Rob: No problem! I work somewhere where they do option 2 as they have 8 web servers. Updating the site node-by-node is problematic without the load balancer, especially when the Session gets changed as part of a deployment.